# Age calculation in RFC 3339 date format in SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, date, converters

I want find age at time of death, in years (e.g., 34). There are two columns named birth and death. How to calculate age from this data,

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yoiTB.png)

Example for one row:

birth date = "0012-08-31T00:53:28+00:53" ,

death date = "0041-01-24T00:53:28+00:53" inSQL.

This is present as a text and have 'None' value. In cases where either the birth or death date are missing the value should read 'Unknown'. If missing the value, new column is age should show 'unknown'.

Comment: You want to write SQL query to get age?

Comment: I'd rather expect 28 years age for the given dates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `TIMESTAMPDIFF` and `CASE` statement for null column

```
SELECT birth_date,
       death_date,
       CASE 
           WHEN birth_date IS NULL OR death_date IS NULL
              THEN 'unknown'
           ELSE TIMESTAMPDIFF(year, birth_date, death_date) 
       END AS Age
FROM table
```

Demo in [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=a02eb68a7fbafe275c5240344f6fa8db)

Comment: 'where either the birth or death date are missing the value should read 'Unknown'.' -?

Comment: It depends on what it wants to display if it is Unknown.

Comment: You should reread the requirement OP wants to display 'Unknown' if dod or dod is null..

Comment: @MeysamAsadi it is not work. Error is: (psycopg2.errors.UndefinedColumn) column "year" does not exist

Comment: @datasever year is not the name of the column in the function but calculates the difference between the two dates in terms of years

Comment: @MeysamAsadi I want to create a new column named age by taking the difference for each row using two columns (birth, death). and it should write 'unknown' when it is an unknown value

Comment: @datasever use case statement.i edited answer see this link : https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=a02eb68a7fbafe275c5240344f6fa8db

Comment: @MeysamAsadi Unfortunately, it gives an error because the date format is not like this.

Comment: @datasever Enter the table definition with your sample data to check.